# How to call main app module function in library module Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android

I'm working on an existing project and would like to call refresh function in main app module from the library module. So when the library module verifyCode is complete it will call the main app's refresh function to refresh the view again.

```
build.gradle(:app)
    
dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
    implementation project(path: ':dependency')
}
```

main app module

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var pref: PreferenceManager
    lateinit var repository: BasicRepository

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pref = PreferenceManager(this)
        setupContentWindow()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

    if (pref.checkCredential()) {
        val intent = PinCodeActivity.intent(this, true, pref.token())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    refresh()
}

private fun refresh() {
    //refresh user data
}
```

library module

```
private void checkCode(String pin, String token) {
    APIManager.getInstance().verifyCode(token, pin, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            String responseUser = response.body();
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                if (responseUser == "true") {
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                    //call main app refresh function after the endpoint return 200
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            } else {
                  //do something
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your build system doesn't send data.  If you want to pass data, you call a method and it returns it.

Comment: I meant how to pass data from the dependency module's file to app module's file? I'm not familiar with Android development so I'm not sure how to name it better. Please feel free to edit my question!

Comment: @GabeSechan I edit the question again it should be more clear now for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data from build gradle files. You need to use intents/broadcasts to send data between modules.

Comment: Or just function calls.  Intents and Broadcasts are only used if the modules are different Activities.  Which is rarely the case (although it can be).

Comment: I meant how to pass data from the dependency module's file to app module's file? I can send data from app modules' file to the dependency module file but not other way around. When I tried "Intent(this, className::class.java)" it doesn't find the className and I can't import it on the top too. I don't know how to reference it other way around. Right now I can pass data dependency -> app only.

Comment: @14079_Z You only use Intents to start an Activity or Service.  Is that what you're trying to do?  Or are you returning data from an Activity to the launcher?  Or are you using the dependency qs a library and you should just be calling functions?  it isn't clear what you're doing here.  But in any case you won't want to make a circular gradle dependency.

Comment: The person who created the project copy the entire dependency file to the project. I'm trying to call some function from app module's file in dependency's file. I don't know to achieve it.